# AD Replication with 3 sites/locations

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, replication

I have created new forest with domain.local.
Domain have 3 locations - A, B, C. ( One dc per location )
First dc-A is owner all  FSMO roles.
After configure all 3 sites with subnets added 3 IP "Inter Site Transports"
dc-A + dc-B
dc-A + dc-C
dc-B + dc-C

Set all of them 
"Cost" - 1 
"Replication Interval" - 15 min 
 
and used recipe for notification for replicate immediately from article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2012/03/25/active-directory-replication-change-notification-you/

then promoted dc-B as Domain Controller and dc-C as domain controller

AD Sites and Services at dc-B and dc-C fully replicated schema from dc-A

All works as expected but... KCC on entire forest created only 4 Connections in NTDS Settings.

dc-A:
< automatically generated > from dc-B
< automatically generated > from dc-C

dc-B:
< automatically generated > from dc-A

dc-C:
< automatically generated > from dc-A

**Why KCC didn't create following replicate connections ???**
dc-B:
< automatically generated > from dc-C
dc-C:
< automatically generated > from dc-B

I don't want create manually connections because notifications won't work then and I'll have to wait 15 min for replication over manually created connections. 
Even I've found tutorial to get notification work at manually connections but don't have to mix connection names :). Want all of them created by KCC.

Tryed many tutorials with recreating connections by repoadmin/kcc dcdiag tests etc ...

How to force KCC to create all of 6 needed **< automatically generated >** connections ???

I'm asking because during inavailability dc-A (FSMO owner) dc-B and dc-C wont replicate with each other.

Comment: Why are you manually creating connections instead of allowing the KCC and ISTG to do the job for you? Why are you hung up on having specific connections created? My suggestion would be to delete the connections that you created and let the KCC and ISTG recreate the replication topology. Why do you think that you need change notification enabled?

Comment: Have you read my post with understanding ? All connections are created by KCC/ISTG  thats why im asking how to force generate all 6 of them by system. Change notification enabled let me replicate changes between sites almost immediately. Minimal value for replication with different sites = 15 min.

Comment: oh god... change "Cost" in site links (have 3 links) value is very important TIP. After many tries got max 5 <automatically generated> connections. When I click "Check Replication Topology" to get last 6th   KCC back to 4 connections. WTF.  When I need to generate connection by KCC/ISTG I need to lowering "Cost" Value but cant get Perfect MIX of that Values to get all 6 Connections generated by KCC/ISTG

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking because during inavailability dc-A (FSMO owner) dc-B and dc-C wont replicate with each other.

Not accurate.

They aren't needed.  If a connection stops working to one site due to network issues, the ISTG will create a connection to the other site.

---

You may want to read the following:

How Active Directory Replication Topology Works - KCC and Topology Generation
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755994(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_repto_how_ludi

Comment: So ... shutdown dc-A for ... 1 hour ex. is answer for my question ? Then create any object at dc-B and dc-C to force replicate with each other ? And I'll have then all 6 < automatically generated > connections ? How many minutes I'll wait for it ?

Comment: Shutdown dc-A for a 1 hour. Wont fixed... Any new ideas ? :/